# NSIS uninstaller privileges according to installer

Tags: nsis, privileges, uninstallation

I have an NSIS installer for an application, which can be run as normal user. But if the user wants to install into the "Program Files" directory, it can still be accomplished by starting the installer with administrator privileges.

Now I have the problem, that the uninstaller is started with user privileges by default, even if the installation took place as administrator. This causes the uninstallation to silently fail. Even worse: It even states that the uninstall process was successful without being able to delete any files.

My question is: Is it possible to create an uninstaller during the installation, which requires (or better: requests itself with) the same privileges as the installation process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to implement this check yourself. You can [check if you are admin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/IsUserAdmin) in the installer with the UserInfo plugin and then store the result in a .ini, the registry or [append](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ReadCustomerData) the info to the uninstaller.exe:

```
InstallDir $temp\instdir

Section

UserInfo::GetAccountType
Pop $0
StrCmp $0 "Admin" 0 +2
StrCpy $0 1
IntOp $0 $0 & 1 ; $0 is now 1 if admin or 0 if not

SetOutPath $InstDir
WriteUninstaller "$InstDir\Uninstall.exe"
FileOpen $1 "$InstDir\Uninstall.exe" a
FileSeek $1 0 END
FileWriteByte $1 $0
FileClose $1

SectionEnd


Section Uninstall

FileOpen $1 "$ExePath" r
FileSeek $1 -1 END
FileReadByte $1 $0
FileClose $1
DetailPrint "Installer was admin: $0"

SectionEnd
```

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful suggestion of storing the info in the uninstaller, as I currently do not write any Registry entries. Any ideas, if it is possible (or maybe not?) if the uninstaller can conditionally do an "RequestExecutionLevel admin" if the installer was run in admin mode?